# EF model doesn't update correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've added a new table to my database then why I tried to update my EF entity model it showed that table as a new table in the list but and I select it
but it wasn't being added yet

I checked the relations and keys
I deleted the entity and re-created it again

here's my uml in database

[image: here's my uml in database]

and this is how the EF generates it, it misses the TeachersCourses table
[image: and this is how the EF generates it, it misses the TeachersCourses table]

Comment: You will need to supply code that you are running. It could be any number of reasons if you're new to EF.

Comment: I've edited my question and added more details

Comment: Does the table have a primary key? EF wont add it unless it does

Comment: Bold Columns are primary keys in db schema

Answer (score 0):

It didn't miss the `TeachersCourses` table :-). It correctly created a navigation property on `Teacher`, called `Courses`. That's how a many to many foreign key relationship is represented in EF when your db schema is well done. Many teachers to many courses.

My only comment is to correct the spelling of the `Course` entity

Comment: this is how the EF named it 
I don't know how it named the singular of Courses as Cours

Comment: and how can I insert data in TeachersCourses  table in this case

Comment: You do, `teacher.Courses.Add(course)` or `course.Teachers.Add(teacher)`

Comment: @MahmoudZakal you can fix the naming since sometimes the ef pluralizer gets singular or plural names wrong.